# len без использования len

Tags: python

> Реализуйте функцию my_len, которая считает длину массива, не используя готовую функцию len, если my_len не может посчитать длину, то должно вернуться сообщение: "Невозможно получить длину этого типа данных"

Решил вот так,но видимо не правильно

```
def f(): 
    my_list = [] 
    for i in range(int(input("Cколько элементов нужно добавить?: "))):
        my_list.append(input("Введи эти элементы: "))
    z = 0
    for letter in my_list:
        z += 1
    if z == 0:
        print("Невозможно получить длину этого типа данных")
    else:
        print("Длина массива:",z, my_list)
f()
```

Comment: А что неправильно? На мой взгляд, проблем нет

Comment: В задании: `Реализуйте функцию my_len, которая ...`. А у вас, такой функции my_len вообще нет. Хотя по существу решение правильное.

Comment: "Невозможно получить длину для этого типа данных"? Это к чему, для какого типа это может сработать? Тем более, что в `my_list` всегда будет список из строк, а для типов, которые не итерабельные бросится исключение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_len(m:list):
    x=0
    try:
        for el in m: x+=1
        return x
    except:
        return 'Невозможно получить длину'
```

Comment: Неверное решение: `my_len( [20,30] ) == 31`

Comment: У вас `x` используется для подсчета кол-ва элементов, и одновременно для прохода по списку. Очевидно, что что-то пойдет не так.

Comment: Исправил ответ. Не досмотрел